# Why are the data from AspNetUser not included in my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

For some reason, I'm able to include all data from other tables, but when it comes to the user table, the information is not passing from the database into the class. I tried the option for lazy loading, with no success.

Let's start: this is what my connection string looks like in `setup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Process class extract

```
public class Process
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedUserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LastUpdatedUserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser LastUpdatedUserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the source of my headache. When a execute the following, the `LastUpdatedUserDetails` does not populate, everything else populates as expected.

```
List<Process> processActivities = context.Process
                                         .Where(e => e.ObjectStatus != ObjectStatus.Deleted && 
                                                     e.ObjectType == ObjectType.Process)
                                         .Include(e => e.ProcessActivities.Where(x => x.ActivityType == ActivityType.Approval && x.ActivityStatus == ObjectStatus.Active))
                                         .ThenInclude(e => e.ActivityRole)
                                         .Include(e => e.ObjectGroup)
                                         .Include(e => e.LastUpdatedUserDetails)
                                         .ToList();
```

This query is generated from the code shown here, and when I run this on the SQL database, the `AspNetUser` details are populated, but it's not pulling into the class.

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CompanyId], [p].[DateCreated], [p].[DocumentPath], [p].[DocumentPathType], [p].[GroupId], [p].[HasFutureState], [p].[LastUpdatedDate], [p].[LastUpdatedUserID], [p].[ObjectOwner], [p].[ObjectOwnerID], [p].[ObjectStatus], [p].[ObjectTags], [p].[ObjectType], [p].[Objectives], [p].[ReviewCycle], [p].[Title], [p].[UniqueId], [p].[Version], [o].[Id], [o].[CompanyId], [o].[Description], [o].[ParentId], [o].[Status], [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[CompanyId], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Country], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[ExpiryDate], [a].[FirstName], [a].[FullName], [a].[LastLogin], [a].[LastName], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[PhotoPath], [a].[RegisterCompanyName], [a].[RoleTitle], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[Status], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName], [a].[UserTeamId], [t].[Id], [t].[ActivityNumber], [t].[ActivityStatus], [t].[ActivityTags], [t].[ActivityType], [t].[AutomatedTaskId], [t].[CreatedDate], [t].[DecisionObjectID], [t].[FlowToDecision], [t].[LastUpdatedDate], [t].[LastUpdatedUserID], [t].[LinkedToDecision], [t].[LoopbackActivityID], [t].[LoopbackFrom], [t].[LoopbackText], [t].[LoopbackTo], [t].[NodeType], [t].[ParallelGroupID], [t].[ProcessID], [t].[ProcessLinkID], [t].[ProgressStatus], [t].[RoleID], [t].[Title], [t].[Id0], [t].[CompanyId], [t].[Description], [t].[Status], [t].[SystemRole]
FROM [Process] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ObjectGroups] AS [o] ON [p].[GroupId] = [o].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [p].[LastUpdatedUserID] = [a].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p0].[Id], [p0].[ActivityNumber], [p0].[ActivityStatus], [p0].[ActivityTags], [p0].[ActivityType], [p0].[AutomatedTaskId], [p0].[CreatedDate], [p0].[DecisionObjectID], [p0].[FlowToDecision], [p0].[LastUpdatedDate], [p0].[LastUpdatedUserID], [p0].[LinkedToDecision], [p0].[LoopbackActivityID], [p0].[LoopbackFrom], [p0].[LoopbackText], [p0].[LoopbackTo], [p0].[NodeType], [p0].[ParallelGroupID], [p0].[ProcessID], [p0].[ProcessLinkID], [p0].[ProgressStatus], [p0].[RoleID], [p0].[Title], [p1].[Id] AS [Id0], [p1].[CompanyId], [p1].[Description], [p1].[Status], [p1].[SystemRole]
    FROM [ProcessActivity] AS [p0]
    INNER JOIN [ProcessRoles] AS [p1] ON [p0].[RoleID] = [p1].[Id]
    WHERE ([p0].[ActivityType] = 1) AND ([p0].[ActivityStatus] = 0)
) AS [t] ON [p].[Id] = [t].[ProcessID]
WHERE ([p].[ObjectStatus] <> 3) AND ([p].[ObjectType] = 1)
ORDER BY [p].[Id], [o].[Id], [a].[Id], [t].[Id], [t].[Id0]
```

You can see, when I put a breakpoint, that the LastUpdatedUserDetails section return null:

[Class Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eKZG.png)

ApplicationUser Class

```
public virtual List<Process> Processes { get; set; }
```

AppDbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Process>().HasOne(x => x.LastUpdatedUserDetails).WithMany(x => x.Processes);
```

Comment: I can't see include AspNetUsers in your query

Comment: Is your Process and LastUpdatedUserDetails entities set up correctly in your dbcontext?  For example: modelBuilder.Entity<Process>().HasOne(x => x.LastUpdatedUserDetails).WithMany(x => x.Processes);

Comment: @jGroot Thank you for the comment, I tried your suggestion, but still, no data is added to the LastUpdatedUserDetails.  I updated my original question to display the changes

Comment: Is the User’s Id field a string like with the Process’ LastUpdatedUserId field? It could be an error with type conversions.

Comment: @LukeWeaver  Both fields are strings, on the database and inside the application.  ApplicationUser is inheriting from IdentityUser.  I first had the field on Process defined as GUID, but when I added the ForeighKey constraint, it forced me to change the LastUpdatedUserID field to a string.

Comment: I’m seeing a lot of examples online where they didn’t even have to specify foreign key, but the property name is always UserId. Try changing “LastUpdatedUserId” to “UserId” and remove that foreign key attribute. This only kind of makes sense to me for security reasons but it’s all I have at the moment..